# Error in Firebase cloud messaging in React PWA

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add FCM into my Reactjs PWA, but I am unable to resolve the below error
[image: Error message]

This a very basic app that fetches some data from firebase and shows it on screen.

[image: Public Directory]

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js')
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(`../firebase-messaging-sw.js`)
      .then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
      });
    }

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: SENDER_ID,
  })

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging()
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Routing from './Components/Routing';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import fire from './config/fire';

function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const msg=fire.messaging();
    msg.requestPermission().then(()=>{
      return msg.getToken();
    }).then((data)=>{
      console.warn("token",data)
    })
  })

  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <div className="App">
        <Routing />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a guess that this is happening because it cannot find any file on the link `http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js` therefore by default of `react-router` it is returning the `index.html` file.